# Sitecore CLI integrate with Visual Studio error

Tags: sitecore-cli

[image][image][image: powershell error]

Poweshell error when trying to run dotnet sitecore ser push

This is my folder structure

Comment: Can you try this command? `dotnet sitecore plugin add -n Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Database --version 5.0.16`

Comment: Unhandled exception: System.Exception: Unhandled exception
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find plugin Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Database in package cache.
   at Sitecore.Devex.Client.Cli.Extensibility.Services.PluginManager.AddPluginAsync(String configPath, String pluginName, String pluginVersion, Boolean overwrite) in C:\BA\ca7111d945a16af4\src\Sitecore.Devex.Client.Cli.Extensibility\Services\PluginManager.cs:l

Comment: Can you check in your `user.json` that you are using `https` in host and authority?

Comment: "host": "http://sitecoretestsc.dev.local",
      "authority": "https://sitecoretestidentityserver.dev.local",   I have changed https now getting this erro Configured source item path /sitecore/content/SitecoreShades/StandBlog did not exist in Sitecore endpoint default (Host: https://sitecoretestsc.dev.local/, DB: master) data store. An empty source indicates that you need to fill that source with data before attempting to push it into a destination. Usually that means you need to pull an initial data set from Sitecore to fill serialized files before being able to push serialized data into Si.

Comment: Did you try this? `dotnet sitecore login --auth https://sitecoretestidentityserver.dev.local --cm https://sitecoretestsc.dev.local --allow-write true`

Comment: So the error you mentioned states that it is not able to find the Sitecore path i.e. `/sitecore/content/SitecoreShades/StandBlog` so can you check in your instance that it exists?

Comment: SitecoreShades is not available anywhere why it is picking how to solve this

Comment: sitecore
Content
Home
StandBlog
StandBlog   in sitecore this way folder available

Comment: You need to check in any of your config files have that entry. Remove that and try again.

Comment: @SumitBhatia  Thankyou for your help now i am able to proceede the issue is same in Project.StandBlog.module.Json i have used SitecoreShades so i am getting this error now resolved

Comment: Great, I have added the information in my answer. Kindly accept it so it can be helpful for other users. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the discussion, you need to update the `user.json` and verify that you are using `HTTPS` in `host` and `authority`. So they should look like this.

```
"host": "https://sitecoretestsc.dev.local", 
"authority": "https://sitecoretestidentityserver.dev.local",
```

Also, you need to verify that the `path` variable that you have provided in the `module.json` contains the correct `Sitecore` content tree path.

This will resolve the issue.

Comment: Ya now solved this way

Comment: Please accept the answer using the right arrow key below the up and down button with my answer. Down to number 0

Comment: Thanks @Sumit,, I was facing the same issue and it got resolved!!